# How can i convert this interface from C# to TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

It declares an interface that will recieve a generic entity and says that this generic entity is from the type BaseEntity

```
public interface IBaseRepository<TEntity>
     where TEntity : BaseEntity
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IBaseRepository<TEntity extends BaseEntity> {

}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQCEEGcoFFIgQCeqA3sKpXAPbUBcqYArgLYBGswAvsKJLIhSoAskXwRCJKAA9oYACZYM2PAWLlKLWgza0ANlARhuvPtHjI0ASUw4ASlAAO1LIWowiAHgAq4yahk5RWUcP2IAPjITYCRqMCwIVAQGGxUHZ1cIdy9RMKJIgF4yLiA)